# Speed up dynamic content delivery

Tags: web-services, cloud-computing, cdn

Imagine a website operating from the US, providing some web services to customers around the world.

Sometimes is takes up to 200ms just to establish a connection between Australia and US.

It's pretty straightforward to accelerate static content delivery by introducing some CDN, but what are the options when dealing with dynamic web services?

Do any of the website accelerator businesses (akamai, cloudflare etc) actually own physical networks, or able to optimize routing between continents to speed up dynamic content delivery?

I know there is an option to clusterize the website itself across continents, but is it really the only way to go?

Answer (score 0):

If the dynamic parts repeat allot and are not unique per session, you can cache them for certain time.
for example, you can request a news list using AJAX and cache the response for 5 min.

The first request will pay the price of slowness but all the others will benefit from the CDN